# How to change font size for the content in asp.update panel

Tags: css, asp.net, html

I'm trying to change the font size for the all the content inside asp.updatePanel ID ="projCheckBoxPanel", I tried both in css and asp.net but they were not working. Here's my code:

```
  <div id="state1" style="width:48%; height:100%; float:left">
        <p  class="label-info" style="font-weight:bold; color:white" >Projects</p>
            <div id="projList" style="height:100%; width:100%; overflow-y:auto">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="projCheckBoxPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="projectSelectAll" runat="server" Text="Select All" OnClick="checkAllProject(this)"  AutoPostBack="false"/><br />  
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListProjects" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" AutoPostBack="false" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="activeBtn" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="inactiveBtn" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with .NET, this is a 100% client-side question. So please do not post your server-side code, post the actual HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code to update the font size. Your `font-weight` is only the thickness of the font, not the size. You need to utilize the CSS style of `font-size` (you can use percentages, em, px, etc.). Also, it would be a good practice to end your code with a `;` (i.e. `<div id="projList" style="height:100%; width:100%; overflow-y:auto;font-size:110%;">`
)

Without accompanying CSS it's hard/impossible do debug as you might have a conflicting class/element that is overriding your font size.

Your code seems to be missing a closing `</div>` too.